# monotouch xamarin referenced project resource files not copied to app bundle

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

As we're accumulating more and more custom components we've started to split these components out into their own projects /  assemblies so we can use them elsewhere easily. I've stumbled across a problem with resources for these components.

I've split out a component and this component has several images for the UI. I've taken the images across into the new project which is a class library and marked all the images as "BundleResource".

This project is referenced by our main application but since doing this the images cannot be loaded. When calling `UIImage.FromFile("TheImage.png");` this just results in a null reference. I've checked the bundle in the MTBS directory of my mac build host and the images have not been copied into it. This is clearly the problem.

Has anyone come across this and found a way to make sure that Resources in referenced projects are copied to the iOS app bundle?

Obviously we can get around this by linking the resources in the referencing project but that's a bit of a nasty workaround.

Comment: I have working resources in an iOS library project. Some images have build action 'content' some have 'BundleResource' both work. The images are a folder (Images) UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/bookmark-hor")

Comment: Interesting, I've made sure it's the right project type (ios library) but for some reason they just aren't appearing in the bundle. I think I'll try recreating the project and copying over everything to see whether anything has gone awry with the project file.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug with the Mac Build Server.  Cleaning solution, rebuilding and redeploying helps.